# lodash: aggregating and reducing array of objects based on date

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, lodash

I am new to Lodash and Functional Programming concepts. So, I have an array of objects with day-wise date like these:

```
[
    {
         "date": '1-Jan-2015',
         "count": 4 
    },
    {
         "date": '4-Jan-2015',
         "count": 3 
    },
    {
         "date": '1-Feb-2015',
         "count": 4 
    },
    {
         "date": '18-Feb-2015',
         "count": 10 
    }
]
```

and I want to reduce and aggregate it in such a way that I get an array of objects where each object has monthly data instead of day-wise data like this:

```
[
    {
        "date": 'Jan, 2015',
        "count": 7 // aggregating the count of January
    },
    {
        "date": 'Feb, 2015',
        "count": 14 //aggregating the count of February
    }
]
```

Currently, I have a written a very unreadable and convoluted code full of ifs and fors which works. However, I want to refactor it using lodash. Is it possible using lodash? I looked around and found `_.reduce` and `_.groupBy` which I can probably use but I am stumped right now and can't figure out a good clean implementation.

Comment: What about year? Will it be same?

Comment: yes, year will be same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `_.reduce` & `_.values`

```
var arr = [
    {
         "date": '1-Jan-2015',
         "count": 4 
    },
    {
         "date": '4-Jan-2015',
         "count": 3 
    },
    {
         "date": '1-Feb-2015',
         "count": 4 
    },
    {
         "date": '18-Feb-2015',
         "count": 10 
    }
]

_.values(_.reduce(arr,function(result,obj){
  var name = obj.date.split('-');
  name = name[1]+', '+name[2];  
  result[name] = {
    date:name,
    count:obj.count + (result[name]?result[name].count:0)
  };
  return result;
},{}));
```

Comment:  Great answer to the question. Thanks and well done sir.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `lodash` to achieve what you want, you could use plain old Javascript:

```
var array = [{
  "date": '1-Jan-2015',
  "count": 4
}, {
  "date": '4-Jan-2015',
  "count": 3
}, {
  "date": '1-Feb-2015',
  "count": 4
}, {
  "date": '18-Feb-2015',
  "count": 10
}]

var result = array.reduce(function(ar, item) {
  var index = item.date.split('-').slice(1,3).join(', ') //getting date Month-Year
  _item = ar.filter(function(a) { 
    return a.date === index
  })[0] // getting item if already present in array

  // getting index of _item if _item is already present in ar
  indexOf = ar.indexOf(_item) 

  if(indexOf > -1)
    // we sum the count of existing _item
    ar[indexOf] = {date: index, count: count: _item.count + item.count } 
  else
    // item is not yet in the array, we push a new _item
    ar.push({date: index, count: item.count}) 

  return ar; // return the array as required by reduce
}, []) // initialize the reduce method with an empty array

console.log(result) // your array with aggregated dates
```

And for the fun, a `lodash` version:

```
_.values(array.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  var index = item.date.split('-').slice(1, 3).join(', ')
  obj[index] = {date: index, count: (obj[index] && obj[index].count || 0) + item.count}
  return obj
}, {}))
```

See [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6m78u5mr/1/)

Comment: I like the fun version  +1

Comment: a little bit shorter indeed ;)